# 起動時に自動でブラウザ表示をさせたい

Tags: windows

Windowsで本体起動時に自動でブラウザで特定のページを全画面で表示するようにしたいのですが、どのようにすればよいのかわからなくて困っております。
なにか良い方法をご存じの方はご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 4):

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -k http://hoge.com/fuga/
```

とスタートアップ等にIEを登録して`-k`オプションで起動すればいいのでは。